# Is there an addon or stand alone program that can generate code for a C# MessageBox?

Tags: c#

Before I add another project on my stack, is there an addon or stand alone program that can generate code for a C# MessageBox? Below is a sample pic of what I'm looking for. I've found some for other languages but none for C#. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the .NET [MessageBox Class (Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.messagebox%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [MessageBox (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox.aspx) both make creating message boxes very, very simple from C#.  Creating a message box is merely a single method call, with all of the options nicely specified in enumerations.

Comment: Hey that's pretty nice. Wish I knew about it a while ago. Thanks!